# Trying to slice, strip, replace characters from text that seems to all be considered one character

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, beautifulsoup, token

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://api.mesowest.net/v2/authapikey=KzdBcPu5cCptvhuS1tagDhZ3CqeQB878nWl")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

myWeather = soup.findAll("body")
token = [elem.text.strip() for elem in myWeather]
rtoken = token[0:1]

print (rtoken)
```

The result of this is: `'{"TOKEN": "7657b5ce64f4425d8a6cf30684e62b18"}'`

I'm trying to grab just the token piece i.e.`"7657b5ce64f4425d8a6cf30684e62b18"`. I've tried the various methods of `token[11,43]`, `[-2,32]` and so on, but all of the characters seem to be defined within `[0]`, hence why the `rtoken = token[0:1]` code is selecting everything, instead of the first character. I've also attempting stripping the needed values as well as replacing and can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: `token` is a **list**, you just built it *using a list comprehension*. The token **string** you want is in the first item in the list, `token[0]`. Note that you should demise your tokens now that you've shared them publicly online.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I've already gotten rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

@Ofer actually gave a *terrible advice*.

*The response content type is JSON - you should not be parsing it with an HTML parser*.

Use the [`.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) of the `requests` Response:

```
import requests

page = requests.get("http://api.mesowest.net/v2/auth?apikey=KzdBcPu5cCptvhuS1tagDhZ3CqeQB878nWl")
token = page.json()['TOKEN']

print (token)
```

Prints:

```
7ed20f28d4d6436fb6083dd9f18a5241
```

Answer (score 0):

your "token" is actually a list, and [0] is just selecting the first (and only?) item in that list, which is a string. if you want to strip the string itself you have to do something like this:

```
    rtoken = token[0][11:43]
```